# React >16.8: How to create a component for dispatch functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to create a component with only reducer functions which can be imported into some component for use.

I created a component with the Context API like this:

```
import React, { useReducer, useContext } from 'react';

import Regress from '../dataObjects/regress';
import { reducer } from './reducer';

const RegressContext = React.createContext();
const RegressConsumer = RegressContext.Consumer;

function RegressProvider(props) {
  const { regressObject } = props;
  const [regress, dispatchToRegress] = useReducer(reducer, !regressObject ? new Regress() : regressObject);

  return(    
      <RegressContext.Provider value={[regress, dispatchToRegress]}>
          {props.children}
      </RegressContext.Provider>
  );
}

const useRegress = () => {
  const contextValue = useContext(RegressContext);
  return contextValue;
};
export { RegressContext, RegressProvider, RegressConsumer, useRegress };
```

I have a JS for the reducer function looking like this:

```
export const reducer = (regress, action) => {
  //some logic
};
```

What im trying to achieve is a new JS/JSX File looking like this:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useRegress } from './useRegress';

export const UpdateProperty = (identifier, item) => { 
    const [,dispatchToRegress] = useRegress();

    const updateProperty = useCallback((identifier, item) => { dispatchToRegress({ type: "update", identifier: identifier, payload: item });
    }, [dispatchToRegress]);

    return (updateProperty);
};
```

If do do this, i get the following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

How can i create a file with all reducer functions, wrapped in a useCallback, ready to be used in any component?

Thank you very much in advance!

edit:

In a random component, I want to use it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { UpdateProperty } from '../components/reducerCommands';

const RequestInfo = (props) => {   

    return (
                <Select updateDispatcher={UpdateProperty} />
    );
}
export default RequestInfo
```

Instead of declaring the dispatch function directly inside the component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { UpdateProperty } from '../components/reducerCommands';

const RequestInfo = (props) => {   

    const updateState = useCallback((newState) => {
        dispatchToRegress({ type: "updateState", newState: newState });
    }, [dispatchToRegress]);  

    return (
<Select updateDispatcher={updateProperty} />
    );
}
export default RequestInfo
```

Comment: how do you use `UpdateProperty`? By it's nature it's custom hook and should be named with `use` as a prefix. Also if you call that `UpdateProperty` in a class as ordinary function you will also get an error.

Comment: @skyboyer i edited my question. Its not a custom hook, the hooks itself is "useRegress" im trying to create an "action" component. Where i write down all my dispatch functions ready to be imported and used in a component